# Is there a way to include a playlist as a variable or link to an external file in Flowplayer?

Tags: php, jquery, flowplayer

I am wondering if there is a way to include a playlist as a variable or link to an external file in Flowplayer. I know that you can use RSS playlists, but I need to use the start and duration parameters to combine clips into a single stream and am not sure that those can be used with RSS playlists.

I would like to be able to keep my playlist external from the player if possible, so that it is easier to manage. What I am trying to do is have a player and several buttons on my page. The buttons each cause a different playlist to be played. I have everything worked out up until the point of actually inserting the playlist.

Right now I am simply writing the content of my playlist file to the player page using a search and replace, but I am hoping there is a better way.

Thank you for reading my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array of JSON objects that can be loaded even by AJAX.

You can also use an external configuration file, that can be generated by PHP itself.

Here are some help links:
http://flowplayer.org/demos/configuration/external.html
http://flowplayer.org/documentation/configuration/playlists.html
http://flowplayer.org/plugins/javascript/playlist.html

Comment: Exactly! You just have to follow the leads on the links.

Comment: I mean you have to use the information given on the links to build the external config. You can generate it with PHP and use the PHP page instead of a config file. Maybe using a http header of `Content-type, application/json`